# Rails4 : how to prevent new action causes caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***Model:***
material has many expresses
express belongs to material

***expressesController.rb***

```
def index
    @express = @material.expresses.new
    @expresses = @material.expresses
end
```

The `@express = @material.expresses.new` causes caching

> CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "expresses".* FROM "expresses" WHERE
>   "expresses"."material_id" = ?  [["material_id", 2]]

this causes the problem that table of expresses always has an extra null row.

How can I fix this?

===========================================
***Edit:***
when I turn `@expresses = @material.expresses` to `@expresses = @material.expresses.all` , this solved the problem.
Why this works?

Answer (score 0):

With `@material.expresses.new` is an alias for  `@material.expresses.build`. This way you create a new instance of `Express` and add it to the association `@material.expresses` I think that's the cause for your null row. It is the currently created express record. Maybe you want this:

```
def index
  @express = Express.new(material: @material)
  @expresses = @material.expresses
end
```